# Problem with Scrolling the Box or Image that is inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have an HTML page that inside there we have a box, the box is a form that need to be submitted.
Anyhow some part of the box is in the current view but some part should be visible when we scroll the page.

We wrote this code but it is not scrolling smoothly, it is jumping!

```
if (!window.matchMedia('(max-width: 64.063em)').matches &&
        !window.matchMedia('(max-width: 40.063em)').matches) {
            window.onscroll = function() { checkOffset() };

            var boxElement = document.getElementById("box");
            var footerElement = document.getElementById("footer");;

            function checkOffset() {
                function getRectTop(el){
                    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                    return rect.top;
                }

                if((getRectTop(boxElement) + document.body.scrollTop) + boxElement.offsetHeight >= 
                    (getRectTop(footerElement) + document.body.scrollTop) - 5) {
                    boxElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                    boxElement.style.bottom = 'auto';

                    }

                if(document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < 
                    (getRectTop(footerElement) + document.body.scrollTop)) {
                    boxElement.style.position = 'fixed'; 
                    boxElement.style.bottom = 0;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Any help will be appreciate
Sepide

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling of box can be achieve through HTML/CSS only, we don't need JS for it, if you have simple requirement list this. please refer below code & run it and see if it helps you in easy way, if you will scroll down/up, box will scroll smoothly.

```css
.main {
  height: 2000px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="box">
Test
</div>
</div>
```